# Equivalent of org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector.getLocalPort() in Jetty 9.x

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

In Jetty 8.1.17.v20150415 I am using the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector.getLocalPort()` method to determine which random HTTP port my Jetty is listening on, using the following line of code:

```
int port = server.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort();
```

However, when I upgrade to a Jetty 9.x (9.3.3.v20150827), I find the `getLocalPort()` method doesn't exist any more. What is the replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that's now in [`NetworkConnector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/NetworkConnector.html) (which extends `Connector`) - presumably because some connectors don't run over a network.

If you *know* that your server will be using a `NetworkConnector`, you could presumably use:

```
NetworkConnector networkConnector = (NetworkConnector) server.getConnectors()[0];
int port = networkConnector.getLocalPort();
```

Comment: That's correct.  There are number of non-network connectors (local, maven managed, http/2 channel, unix sockets, pipes, etc...)